# elasticsearch exception with more_like_this in django-haystack

Tags: elasticsearch, django-haystack

i'm having a problem with more_like_this function of django-haystack in configuration with elasticsearch - for some reason it returns some strange error in console. here is a code in python:

```
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
sqs= SearchQuerySet().filter(django_ct__exact='myapp.mymodel')
similar_items= sqs.more_like_this(myapp.mymodel.object)
```

this actually returns the results from all models, despite the filtering (it's a dirty trick, i know, sorry)

plus there's a message in the log:

```
Failed to fetch More Like This from Elasticsearch for document 'myapp.mymodel.21': Non-OK response returned (500):
u'SearchPhaseExecutionException [
Failed to execute phase [query],
total failure;
shardFailures {
[GKAIomI1QXedjKQOh5dcbw][haystack][0]: RemoteTransportException[[Amina Synge] [inet[/192.168.1.100:9302]][search/phase/query]];
nested: SearchParseException [[haystack][0]: from[20],
 size[-1]: Parse Failure [
     Failed to parse source [
         {"from":20,
          "size":-10,
          "query":{
              "bool":{
                  "must_not":{"term":{"_uid":"modelresult#myapp.mymodel.21"}},
                  "should":[{"mlt_field":{"django_id":{"like_text":"21"}}},
                            {"mlt_field":{"text":{"like_text":"<mymodel.textfield content>"}}},
                            {"mlt_field":{"user":{"like_text":"<mymodel.instance.username>"}}},
                            {"mlt_field":{"mymodel.instance_id":{"like_text":"21"}}},
                            {"mlt_field":{"id":{"like_text":"myapp.mymodel.21"}}}]}}}]]];
nested: SearchParseException[[haystack][0]: from[20],size[-1]: Parse Failure [size is set to [-10] and is expected to be higher or equal to 0]]; }
```

i'm new to elasticsearch, so, i don't really understand what this exception means, and how to change `size`. simply couldn't find it in the manuals. the search by phrases works perfectly, only `more_like_this` produces this error.

any help, any hint is highly appreciated, and sorry for possibly lame question

Comment: This is the key here: `size is set to [-10] and is expected to be higher or equal to 0`. It looks like you are trying to retrieve -10 records.

Comment: precisely! it is django-haystack's who is somehow trying to retrieve -10 records, and i honestly have no idea where to look for the reason of such behavior, and how to fix it..

Comment: no clues, really? i have to solve the problem asap, but various experiments didn't bring any result..